# While storing data in sqlite database its not saving data after some values

Tags: sqlite

I have a sensor attach to raspberrypi and an application containing function like read, write, erase etc. which stores the data at sqlite database, read the sqlite databse or erase the database. So, my problem is at log read functionality sometimes data is getting stuck at 853 value, it is not storing value more than 853 in database. I am unable to find the reason behind it.